# How to read configuration settings (like installation folder,application name etc) for NSIS script from a xml config file

Tags: nsis

I am working on a installer for a .net window based project. I had developed a custom windows installer screns in windows form. Now I save all details collected on form in an config file. 
If any body could tell me, how I can read this config file in NSIS script to assign configuration steetings like installation folder, appication name etc to nsis script from config file. 
I had tried to used nsisXML.dll for this but failed to achive...
Any help will be highly appriciated...

Comment: Maybe you could post your code that does not work...